# Success when deploy with Out bound change set, fail with deploy with Force.com IDE or Mavensmate

Tags: apex, unit-test, deployment, force.com-ide

So this is been going on for a while. Everything works when I use the build in outbound/inbound change set to deploy code form Sandbox to Production. And Fails every time trying to deploy the exact same code using either Force.com IDE (Eclipse) or Mavensmate. I get test class failure. "No such column ..... on entity". But the test class pass just fine when I run them in developer console. Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I can think of:

One, your package.xml file is out of date and you need to refresh - perhaps you are only refreshing selected parts of it. Do a system wide refresh.

Two, make sure you are at the latest possible api level - perhaps the object you are deploying has changed with an api update and your older version in package.xml contains an out of date version (with fields that are no longer there)

Comment: I tried both of them, didn't help. Just wondering what are the differences when you deploy from SF UI vs IDE (tooling api)

Comment: At https://gearset.com, we are building a service that aims to fix all these pesky deployment problems and get to a stage where deployment Just Works.

Would you be interested in working with us to help diagnose what issue you have and see if our service fixes it for you?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like below,

1) Find the field mentioned in the class failure("No such column ..... on entity")

2) Add the field also in package.xml. For example check below,

```
<types>
<members>Case.EngineeringReqNumber__c</members>
<name>CustomField</name>
</types>
```

3 Try to deploy.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me